# Get Python script return in HTML

Tags: python, html, json, parse-platform

I will develop Python scripts to be used by HTML+CSS developer in front-end of website. Right now, I'm trying to run some initial tests to see how this would work. I use `parse.com` for backend and for example, the following script would retrieve some data in database:

```
import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('GET', '/1/classes/ParseClass', '', {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "appIDHere",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "appKeyHere"
     })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result
```

When I run this script, it correctly print the results JSON encoded. Now, in a HTML file, developer would call `thisScript.py`. My question is, how would the HTML developer get the results from this script? Since he won't be coding in Python, he needs everything ready to use in HTML. That's pretty much what we are trying to achieve.

Here is the output of the script in JSON, just for reference:

```
{u'results': [{u'objectId': u'4x9rY7a1q8', u'usuario': {u'className': u'_User', u'__type':       u'Pointer', u'objectId': u'W9ifgHpbov'}, u'dataEHora': {u'iso': u'2014-04-28T13:41:48.980Z',     u'__type': u'Date'}, u'updatedAt': u'2014-04-28T13:41:48.460Z', u'userConfigOrientador':     {u'className': u'UserConfigOrientador', u'__type': u'Pointer', u'objectId': u'2QT8Ce6R3d'},     u'createdAt': u'2014-04-28T13:41:48.460Z'}, {u'objectId': u'RpeAsJB1qS', u'usuario': {u'className':     u'_User', u'__type': u'Pointer', u'objectId': u'W9ifgHpbov'}, u'dataEHora': {u'iso': u'2014-04-    28T13:43:00.093Z', u'__type': u'Date'}, u'updatedAt': u'2014-04-28T13:42:59.476Z', u'userConfigOrientador': {u'className': u'UserConfigOrientador', u'__type': u'Pointer', u'objectId': u'2QT8Ce6R3d'}, u'createdAt': u'2014-04-28T13:42:59.476Z'}, {u'objectId': u'AI6Vg7weAI', u'usuario': {u'className': u'_User', u'__type': u'Pointer', u'objectId': u'W9ifgHpbov'}, u'dataEHora': {u'iso': u'2014-04-28T13:46:31.322Z', u'__type': u'Date'}, u'updatedAt': u'2014-04-28T13:46:30.706Z', u'userConfigOrientador': {u'className': u'UserConfigOrientador', u'__type': u'Pointer', u'objectId': u'2QT8Ce6R3d'}, u'createdAt': u'2014-04-28T13:46:30.706Z'}, {u'objectId': u'Yeh24Zt5Af', u'usuario': {u'className': u'_User', u'__type': u'Pointer', u'objectId': u'W9ifgHpbov'}, u'dataEHora': {u'iso': u'2014-04-28T13:46:57.462Z', u'__type': u'Date'}, u'updatedAt': u'2014-04-28T13:46:56.845Z', u'userConfigOrientador': {u'className': u'UserConfigOrientador', u'__type': u'Pointer', u'objectId': u'2QT8Ce6R3d'}, u'createdAt': u'2014-04-28T13:46:56.845Z'}, {u'objectId': u'gtKTIvUbGZ', u'usuario': {u'className': u'_User', u'__type': u'Pointer', u'objectId': u'W9ifgHpbov'}, u'dataEHora': {u'iso': u'2014-05-30T16:22:00.000Z', u'__type': u'Date'}, u'updatedAt': u'2014-04-28T16:22:40.428Z', u'userConfigOrientador': {u'className': u'UserConfigOrientador', u'__type': u'Pointer', u'objectId': u'2QT8Ce6R3d'}, u'createdAt': u'2014-04-28T16:22:17.734Z'}, {u'objectId': u'uZFxtopxDw', u'usuario': {u'className': u'_User', u'__type': u'Pointer', u'objectId': u'W9ifgHpbov'}, u'dataEHora': {u'iso': u'2014-05-31T16:22:00.000Z', u'__type': u'Date'}, u'updatedAt': u'2014-04-28T16:22:41.545Z', u'userConfigOrientador': {u'className': u'UserConfigOrientador', u'__type': u'Pointer', u'objectId': u'2QT8Ce6R3d'}, u'createdAt': u'2014-04-28T16:22:23.282Z'}, {u'objectId': u'z5zAqBqENX', u'usuario': {u'className': u'_User', u'__type': u'Pointer', u'objectId': u'W9ifgHpbov'}, u'dataEHora': {u'iso': u'2014-05-09T18:40:00.000Z', u'__type': u'Date'}, u'updatedAt': u'2014-04-28T18:46:48.442Z', u'userConfigOrientador': {u'className': u'UserConfigOrientador', u'__type': u'Pointer', u'objectId': u'2QT8Ce6R3d'}, u'createdAt': u'2014-04-28T18:40:27.610Z'}, {u'objectId': u'JvCSNjUA80', u'usuario': {u'className': u'_User', u'__type': u'Pointer', u'objectId': u'W9ifgHpbov'}, u'dataEHora': {u'iso': u'2014-04-18T18:40:00.000Z', u'__type': u'Date'}, u'updatedAt': u'2014-04-28T18:46:47.059Z', u'userConfigOrientador': {u'className': u'UserConfigOrientador', u'__type': u'Pointer', u'objectId': u'2QT8Ce6R3d'}, u'createdAt': u'2014-04-28T18:40:30.926Z'}]}
```

By the way, this is an array of `PFObjects`, used in `parse.com`.

These scripts can also be made in JavaScript, if it changes anything.

Comment: `print json.dumps(result)` should generate a json encoded string, which your front-end dev can retrieve and use using javascript.

Comment: Thanks. But he doesn't have any experience with `javaScript`. I would need to give him the data ready. He will be responsible for the design part of website only.

Comment: Would it be easier if I got the HTML,CSS design and then implement the data myself? Even though I don't have any HTML, CSS experience?

Comment: I'm pretty confused about what you are trying to do :). If you know how to use javascript, you can get this data provided by your server, via AJAX calls. Then fill in the data on the HTML page as you required.

Comment: I can to the scripts in python using parse's rest api. I have a developer who doesn't have any experience with python or javascript to do the `UI`. I know my way around python, but not so much `JavaScript`. Since I built the database for other apps and know how it should work, I'm just trying to figure out if it's best for me to develop the scripts to be used in HTML or if I should get the `UI` from other developer (since I can't code in HTML, CSS) and make the connections myself.

Comment: Your designer have 0 knowledge of `javascript` and you have minimal knowledge, so obviously you should be handling it, and ask the designer to fill in with dummy data and finish the design. And before you start working on `javascript`, just google your way through best practices for `AJAX`. You might want to learn `jquery` too which is absolutely a life+time saver. (at least, it is for me). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Taking JSON data and displaying information is going to require some JavaScript knowledge unless you want to do lots of dynamic HTML generation.

You could consider using some kind of Template engine. I use [KendoUI](http://www.kendoui.com) which just recently went free for most parts, and has many features to help display data.

If neither your designer or yourself want to learn JavaScript then you will need to take the data and use it to generate the HTML yourself in Python.

Comment: About generating HTML in Python, I could do that, but that would be duplicated work, right? Since my designer would be already working on designing the pages it would be a waste to generate HTML in Python. Am I right? I think JavaScript will be the best option here.

Comment: @Jorge learning JavaScript is the best option, there's so much you can do... it is like the glue that holds the internet together :)